# Creating a process in Linux with a different mount namespace

Tags: linux

I'm trying to create a process that has a different mnt namespace from his parent.

For that, I use the following code:

```
static int childFunc(void *arg){
    if (mount("/","/myfs", "sysfs", 0, NULL) == -1) 
        errExit("mount");
    printf("Starting new bash. Child PID is %d\n",getpid());
    execle("/bin/bash",NULL);
    printf("Shouldn't arrive here.\n");
    return 0;           /* Child terminates now */
}

#define STACK_SIZE (1024 * 1024)    /* Stack size for cloned child */

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    char *stack;                    /* Start of stack buffer */
    char *stackTop;                 /* End of stack buffer */
    pid_t pid;

    /* Allocate stack for child */
    stack = malloc(STACK_SIZE);
    if (stack == NULL)
        errExit("malloc");
    stackTop = stack + STACK_SIZE;  /* Assume stack grows downward */

    /* Create child that has its own MNT namespaces*/
    pid = clone(childFunc, stackTop, CLONE_NEWNS | SIGCHLD, argv[1]);
    if (pid == -1)
        errExit("clone");
    printf("clone() returned %ld\n", (long) pid);
    sleep(1); 

    if (waitpid(pid, NULL, 0) == -1)    /* Wait for child */
        errExit("waitpid");
    printf("child has terminated\n");
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

When running it, I do get a bash shell, running in a different MNT namespace.
In order to verify it, I execute in another shell `sudo ls -l /proc/<child_pid>/ns`, and I indeed see that the child process has a different namespace from the rest of the processes in the system.

However, if I execute `mount` from both of the shells - I get the same FSTAB output, and the line `myfs on /myfs type sysfs (rw,relatime)` appears in both of them.

What is the explanation for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to mark the the existing mounts as "private" before creating the new namespace:

```
mount --make-rprivate /
```

Comment: I need to admit that I don't know how. I would also argue that this action should be done by the administrator rather than implicitly by a process since it affects the whole system. But sure, `mount` is written in `C` so there is a way. I would suggest read the code of the `mount` command.